# VSCode: run remote Jupyter server with remote notebook files, all on same remote machine

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-remote

If my notebook files are local, I can launch a remote Jupyter server, connect to it, and have that server run my code. The problem is, the notebook files and all the data are still local. I want everything to be remote.

I've installed the Remote Development extension pack, which includes Remote SSH. With that, I am able to connect to the remote system and open the folder where my notebooks are. However, I cannot run any notebooks this way. If I click the Run button, it prompts me to select a kernel.

So I launch a remote kernel on that same machine (see first paragraph), copy the URL it prints out, and paste that into VSCode. Nothing happens, literally nothing, I hit Enter and there's no change.

So the problem is I can do each step separately (connect to a remote Jupyter server, or open a file on the remote machine), but I cannot do both at once (open a notebook file remotely and run it with a remote kernel).

---

If I use the traditional route of launching a Jupyter notebook server on the remote machine, copy the URL it prints out, paste it into Chrome - that works great in Chrome. That way I can run the kernel remotely, and have my notebook files also remote.

I wish I could do a remote server / remote notebooks session with VSCode as well.

Note: the remote machine is Ubuntu 22.04 and I have full access to all ports.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, if you install the local extensions onto the remote server, this all starts working. I could not execute remote notebooks because the remote VSCode server had no Jupyter or Python extensions. With that done, everything works now.